# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un campo en una tabla existente y asignarle un valor vacio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito agregar un campo a una tabla existente, pero al momento de agregarla me llena por default un valor NULL, necesito que el dato que tenga el campo esté completamente vacio (Osea un ='')

Hice este query pero, me podrían ayudar agregando qué me falta para que pueda solucionar mi problema?

```
CREATE TABLE TablaPrueba (Codigo INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE TablaPrueba 
ADD Descripcion VARCHAR(50)
```

Comment: `NULL` es la representacion de nulos en sql server, si ves una tupla que en uno de sus valores no dice NULL pero tu lo ves vacio (en balnco), en ella existe un `string`, digase un espacio etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplica esto para SQL Server después de crear tu tabla y agregar tu columna.

```
ALTER TABLE TablaPrueba ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Descripcion DEFAULT N'' FOR Descripcion;
```

Comment: Está muy bien, pero si la tabla tiene datos (Hablando de la columna codigo y nombre) me sigue apareciendo en "NULL" en Descripcion

Comment: Después de ello podrías hacer un (UPDATE TablaPrueba SET Descripcion = '' )